# How to pass parameter to Java using HTML

Tags: html, jsp, jakarta-ee, parameters, request

I am new to Java and programming in general. For background, I am working on my simple survey system. I have all the classes/methods necessary to insert and pull from MySQL and display the survey on my JSP page.

This is my Index.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Survey System</title>
</head>
<body>                
    <h1>Survey List</h1>
    <%            
        ResultSet resultset = new controller.SelectSurvey().SelectSurvey();    

        if (request.getParameter("btnControlSurvey") != null){
            response.sendRedirect("controlsurvey.jsp");
        }

        if (request.getParameter("btnTakeSurvey") != null){
            response.sendRedirect("takesurvey.jsp");                   
        }
    %>
    <form name = 'surveylist' action="index.jsp" method="POST">             
        <table border="0">                
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>                        
                    <td>
                        <select id="listsurvey">
                            <% while (resultset.next()) {                                     
                            %>
                            <option><%= resultset.getString("survey_ID")%> - <%= resultset.getString("title")%></option>
                            <% } %>
                        </select>
                    </td>                        
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="TAKE SURVEY" name = "btnTakeSurvey" />                            
                    </td>
                </tr>                                                                                                     
            </tbody>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="CONTROL SURVEY" name = "btnControlSurvey" />                                         
            </td>
        </table>
    </form>                            
</body>
```

How do I pass the selected surveyID value in my drop down list with ID listsurvey to my hard-coded surveyID1 variable in my Takesurvey.jsp (see below) once the Submit button is clicked?

```
<%            
    int surveyID1 = 1;
    ResultSet rsSurvey = new controller.SelectSurvey().SelectSurveyByID(surveyID1);
    ResultSet rsSurveyQuestion = new controller.SelectSurvey().SelectQuestionByID(surveyID1);
%>
```

I found that there are at least three ways to do this as listed below. What would be the easiest way and would you please give me an example?

Putting values into the session object.
Putting values into the application object
Putting values at the end of the redirect URL.

Your inputs are very appreciated.

Thank you and have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're doing in that 2nd code segment, but you can get a hold of the form parameters using

```
String surveyId = request.getParameter(listsurvey);
```

It looks like you're looking for an **int** on the other side, but it comes in as a **String** so just use **Integer.parseInt()** after you pull it from the request.

**Note:** The request variable is already implicitly available in your JSP. You don't have to declare it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: You cannot cast a String to an int... You need to use Integer.parseInt

Comment: this is true! fixed my terminology

Comment: My 2nd code segment is in another jsp page, so your code won't work. Thank you for your input.

Comment: I was able to figured out and made it work with your code example. But I needed to change my form action to takesurvey.jsp and that made my control survey button to load the takesurvey.jsp page as well which is an issue. Therefore, I cant use request.getParameter.

Comment: could you please give me best answer then please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the surveyID in the HTTP page request using either GET or POST. Then in the servlet / JSP you can use request.getParameter("surveyID")

Comment: Would you please give me an example?

Comment: Please see my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by using request.getParameters and use different forms for each button and it works as wanted.

Thank you for all of yours input again guys.